# How to import model along with embed texture in blender?

Tags: texturing, import, .fbx

I have a FBX model with embed texture. When I import the model in blender the model get import but not its texture. Model has a bitmap texture folder from which it has to call texture. Now how can I call all the texture from that bitmap folder so that the FBX model import all the textures.

Comment: Usually, textures it comes with the name of the material and its mapa! example: materialA_Normalmap ... how is it there for you?

Comment: I don't know how to know that? The model is exported from 3DS MAX with embed texture than it imported in blender.

Comment: in the texture folder, can you see the images?

Comment: Yes I can see images. They are ,jpeg

Comment: Any reply from you folks will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

first: Activate the node add ons[image]

Second: In shader editor: click in principled bsdf, after press shift + ctrl + t, and select all texture

[image]